# Why doesn't my string get passed down to my equation after converting it into a double?

Tags: java, android

I am working in Android Studio and have to create an app that allows the user to enter in the price of a meal they've had then select their tip amount from a drop box (5%, 10%, 15%, 20%, and 25%) and then be able to click a button to get the final total for their meal. I have everything pretty much done except for calculating the total. This is my code so far:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
double mealCost;
double totalCharges;
double tip;
String tipPercent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final EditText mealAmount = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMealAmount);
    final Spinner group =(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.txtGroup);
    Button charges = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCharge);
           charges.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               final TextView result = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtResult));
               @Override
               public void onClick(View view) {
                   String holdEditText = "";
                   holdEditText = mealAmount.getText().toString();

                   try {
                       mealCost = Double.parseDouble(holdEditText);
                   } catch (NumberFormatException d) {
                       mealCost = 0;
                   }

                   DecimalFormat currency = new DecimalFormat("$###,###.##");
                   tipPercent = group.getSelectedItem().toString();

                   try {
                       tip = Double.parseDouble(tipPercent);
                   } catch (NumberFormatException d) {
                       tip = 0;
                   }

                   totalCharges = mealCost + (mealCost + tip);
                   result.setText("Total cost of a meal that is $" + mealCost + " and a tip of "
                           + tipPercent + " is " + currency.format(totalCharges));
           }
});
```

}}

The problem that I run into is in this line of code:

```
totalCharges = mealCost + (mealCost + tip);
```

When the app goes to calculate the total it always makes the tip become 0 instead of taking into account which tip percentage the user has chosen from the drop box. I have tried taking out the "tip = 0;" section of the code but that just ends up making the app ignore the tip completely. I have been stuck on this for a while and have no idea what to do. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Well, a good place to start would be not catching the `NumberFormatException` and letting it error out so you can see what happened.

Comment: `tipPercent = group.getSelectedItem().toString()` looks suspicious, it only works if your selected item is a `String`. Can you post the code for your Spinner adapter?

Comment: I'm fairly new to both java and android studio so I'm unsure how to access the code for my spinner adapter. This is what I have for my selection in my spinner in the app though:

Comment: <string-array name="txt_group">
        <item>5%</item>
        <item>10%</item>
        <item>15%</item>
        <item>20%</item>
        <item>25%</item>
    </string-array>

Comment: @CodieBetlinski Right, you can't parse the percentage to double that way, you should convert these percentages, say 5% to 0.05 before you parse them.

Comment: Once you get the value of `tip` sorted, you need to change your formula for calculating the total amount `totalCharges = mealCost + (mealCost * tip);`, ie. replace the second `+` with a `*`. Or more simply: `totalCharges = mealCost * (1 + tip);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `tipPercent` is of type **5%**, you can try something like below:

```
Double tip = new Double(tipPercent.trim().replace("%", ""))/100;
```

and the resulting value of tip will be **0.05**